# Django Path to static files changing depending on the page

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-urls

I have an index page with a list of mouvements in a datatable, each row has buttons that allow the user to press "Edit" to go to a new page where he can view the details of the mouvement.

On index page and on the basic details mouvement page everything work fine, static files are loaded with the path /gestion_mouvements/static/...

But when i use "(?P[0-9]+)/$" in my page url to be able to get the mouvement ID in the url, the loaded page change static path to gestion_mouvements/mouvementDetails/static/... for example and fail to load the static files since the path should be gestion_mouvements/static/...

I checked and tried many different static settings in settings.py but nothing worked so far, anyone has an idea on how i can change that ?

This is my urls.py from the app

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('Gestion_Mouvement.views',
    url(r'^tableau/(?P<idMI>\d+)$','tableau', name = 'tableau'),
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^tableau',tableau, name = 'tableau'),
    url(r'^mouvementDetails/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 'mouvementDetails', name = 'mouvementDetails'),
    url(r'^index', index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^refresh_index','refresh_index', name = 'refresh_index'),
    url(r'^finalisation','finalisation', name = 'finalisation'),
    url(r'^creation','creation', name = 'creation'),
    url(r'^historiques','histos', name = 'histos'),
    url(r'^histo-pt0','histosPT0', name = 'histo-pt0'),
    url(r'^histo-entrants','histosEntrants', name = 'histo-entrants'),
    url(r'^histo-sortants','histosSortants', name = 'histo-sortants'),
)
```

my index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="../static\css/Gestion_Mouvements.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../static\css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet' %}" media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css//bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#indexTab').dataTable( {
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "lengthMenu": [ [-1], ["All"] ]
} );
 $('.editbtn').click(function(){
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $text = $row.find(".idMark").text(); // Find the text
        alert($text);
    });
 $('.deletebtn').click(function(){
       var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
       var $text = $row.find(".idMark").text(); // Find the text
       alert($text);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Shape1" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:5px;width:1300px;height:100px;z-index:0;">
<img src="../static\images/img0003.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="width:1300px;height:100px;"></div>
<div id="Html1" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:107px;width:1300px;height:400px;z-index:1">
<table id="indexTab" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date et heure création</th>
                <th>Véhicule</th>
                <th>Pesée 1</th>
                <th>Type mouvement</th>
                <th>Sous type</th>
                <th>Code espèce</th>
                <th>Libellé espèce</th>
                <th>Edit / Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
           {% for mouvement in mouvements %}
            <tr  name="mvtRow{{mouvement.Id}}">
            <th class="idMark">{{mouvement.Id}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l7">{{mouvement.DateHeureCreat}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l8">{{mouvement.Immat_Transporteur}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l9">{{mouvement.Poids_Charge}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l2">{{mouvement.Type_Mouvement}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l8">{{mouvement.Sous_Domaine}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce3l9">{{mouvement.Espece}}</span></th>
            <th class="ce312">{{mouvement.Libelle}}</span></th>
            <th><a href="/gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/{{mouvement.Id}}"><button type="button" class="editbtn">Edit</button> <a href="/gestion_mouvement/tableau"><button class="deletebtn">Delete</button></a></th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table></div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:15px;top:17px;width:900px;height:30px;line-height:30px;z-index:2;" name="ebFluxState" value="{{listOPT.0}}" readonly spellcheck="false">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="btn_PeseeSilo" value="Pesée Silo" style="position:absolute;left:936px;top:17px;width:96px;height:40px;z-index:3;">
<input type="submit" id="Button2" name="btn_createManual" value="Création Manuelle" style="position:absolute;left:1037px;top:17px;width:119px;height:40px;z-index:4;">
<input type="submit" id="Button3" name="btn_refresh" value="Rafraichissement" style="position:absolute;left:1174px;top:17px;width:119px;height:40px;z-index:5;">
</body>
</html>
```

and my settings.py STATIC options :

```
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static').replace('\\', '/')
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../templates'),
)
```

The links to js/css files are exactly the same in the other page, they are called exactly the same way and yet still the /mouvementDetails/ get added to every path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every other thing is perfectly set. You need to change a snippet of HTML file, like this :

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="../static\css/Gestion_Mouvements.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../static\css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet' %}" media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css//bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
```

To :

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="{% static 'css/Gestion_Mouvements.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet' %}" media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css//bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Because of **../static** searches for all possible combinations based on the relative path of static folder and project/app.

Comment: I understand the problem, but those two lines are generated by WYSIWYG, i can re write them on eclipse but my problem isn't on the index page, it's on the mouvementDetails/[ID] but i do have the same problem au auto generated line that miss the django format.

Comment: @Girardclément At **mouvementDetails/[ID]** url, which template is getting rendered. There might be some problem. Like **{% load static %}** might not be defined there or this file is not getting extended there.

Comment: @Girardclément Please show the view and template code of url **mouvementDetails/[ID]**.

Comment: i tried but the template is way too long to be added. but i have tried to replace every call to js / img / css by a django call and it work perfectly, my problem is now that WYSIWYG is generating it's own code that doesn't work with Django

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Well, now that you provided the relevant information, the problem is clear, see comments.

Some more information e.g. your static settings in `settings.py` would be very helpful. However, it probably boils down to these things:

In `settings.py`, be sure to set your `STATIC_URL`, in your case to `/static/`:

```
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then, in your template:

```
# your_template.html
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: I do have those settings, they work perfectly on all my pages, execpt the one where i use "(?P[0-9]+)/$"...

Comment: No, you don't. You have two relative paths `../static` instead of using `{% static`. There's the problem.